# Button stops working after multiple clicks

Tags: android, button

Good day people!

I'm having a literal crisis with this app I'm working on. The objective of this one button is to start an animation. Included in the method it launches, disables the button until the animation finishes. Here is the method the button calls:

```
leftTrigger.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            leftTrigger.setEnabled(false);
            if(!computerTurn && !isPlayerLeftAttacking){
                playerLeftHitting();
            }else if(computerTurn && !isPlayerLeftEvading){
                playerLeftEvading();
            }
        }
    });
private void playerLeftEvading(){
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            isPlayerLeftEvading = true;
            float origin = playerLeft.getX();
            while(playerLeft.getX()>origin-500){
                playerLeft.setX(playerLeft.getX()-15);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            playerLeft.setX(origin);
            isPlayerLeftEvading = false;
            Handler handler = getWindow().getDecorView().getHandler();
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    leftTrigger.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

What happens is, after multiple times I press the button, the button suddenly stops working and it gets a darker shade of color. There are no error logs in the logcat. So what am I doing wrong? What causes these kinds of issue and how can we resolve it?

**EDIT** as per requested, Here is the Logcat log filtered to output only my project:

```
10-13 13:35:34.952 12502-12502/? E/Zygote: v2
10-13 13:35:34.952 12502-12502/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10161
10-13 13:35:34.952 12502-12502/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
10-13 13:35:34.952 12502-12502/? W/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], priority [2], priority version is VE=SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1_0034
10-13 13:35:34.952 12502-12502/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
10-13 13:35:34.962 12502-12502/? W/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.example.dale.projectapp 
10-13 13:35:34.962 12502-12502/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
10-13 13:35:34.972 12502-12502/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
10-13 13:35:34.972 12502-12502/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
10-13 13:35:34.992 12502-12508/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
10-13 13:35:34.992 12502-12508/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
10-13 13:35:35.002 12502-12502/? W/ResourcesManager: Resource getTopLevelResources for package com.example.dale.projectappoverlayDirs =Null
10-13 13:35:35.002 12502-12502/? W/ActivityThread: Application com.example.dale.projectapp is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
10-13 13:35:35.002 12502-12502/? I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
10-13 13:35:36.472 12502-12508/com.example.dale.projectapp I/art: Debugger is active
10-13 13:35:36.602 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp I/System.out: Debugger has connected
10-13 13:35:36.602 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
10-13 13:35:36.802 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
10-13 13:35:37.002 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
10-13 13:35:37.202 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
10-13 13:35:37.402 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
10-13 13:35:37.602 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
10-13 13:35:37.802 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
10-13 13:35:38.002 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp I/System.out: debugger has settled (1344)
10-13 13:35:38.072 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.dale.projectapp-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.dale.projectapp-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
10-13 13:35:38.282 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.dale.projectapp-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.dale.projectapp-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
10-13 13:35:38.342 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.dale.projectapp-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.dale.projectapp-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
10-13 13:35:38.402 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.dale.projectapp-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.dale.projectapp-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
10-13 13:35:38.472 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.dale.projectapp-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.dale.projectapp-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
10-13 13:35:38.542 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.dale.projectapp-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.dale.projectapp-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
10-13 13:35:38.602 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.dale.projectapp-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.dale.projectapp-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
10-13 13:35:38.652 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.dale.projectapp-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.dale.projectapp-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
10-13 13:35:38.712 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.dale.projectapp-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.dale.projectapp-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
10-13 13:35:38.772 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.dale.projectapp-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.dale.projectapp-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
10-13 13:35:38.832 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.dale.projectapp-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.dale.projectapp-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
10-13 13:35:38.832 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.dale.projectapp-1/lib/arm
10-13 13:35:38.842 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ContextRelationManager: ContextRelationManager() : FEATURE_ENABLED=true
10-13 13:35:38.842 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
10-13 13:35:38.952 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
10-13 13:35:39.142 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
10-13 13:35:39.142 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{5733430 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
10-13 13:35:39.142 12502-12598/com.example.dale.projectapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
10-13 13:35:39.182 12502-12598/com.example.dale.projectapp D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xdf67f7c4
10-13 13:35:39.182 12502-12598/com.example.dale.projectapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-13 13:35:39.182 12502-12598/com.example.dale.projectapp D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1080x1920]-format:1
10-13 13:35:39.192 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
10-13 13:35:39.192 12502-12598/com.example.dale.projectapp D/libGLESv1: STS_GLApi : DTS is not allowed for Package : com.example.dale.projectapp
10-13 13:35:39.232 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@651d72c time:18183958
10-13 13:35:45.852 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:35:45.942 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:35:45.942 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.dale.projectapp time:18190662
10-13 13:35:45.992 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp E/Qmage: isQIO : stream is not a QIO file
10-13 13:35:45.992 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp E/Qmage: isQIO : stream is not a QIO file
10-13 13:35:45.992 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp E/Qmage: isQIO : stream is not a QIO file
10-13 13:35:46.002 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
10-13 13:35:46.002 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{aae07ab I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
10-13 13:35:46.032 12502-12598/com.example.dale.projectapp D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1080x1920]-format:1

                                                                          [ 10-13 13:35:46.052 12502:12610 W/         ]
                                                                          g2d fimg library does not exist
10-13 13:35:46.062 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
10-13 13:35:46.152 12502-12598/com.example.dale.projectapp D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xf34ebb00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xf3536970
10-13 13:35:46.152 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@8bda5fa time:18190875
10-13 13:35:46.322 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{57d4c7f token=android.os.BinderProxy@651d72c {com.example.dale.projectapp/com.example.dale.projectapp.Main_Menu}} show : false
10-13 13:35:46.812 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:35:46.882 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:35:46.882 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.dale.projectapp time:18191606
10-13 13:35:47.112 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
10-13 13:35:47.112 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{5f2f4dc I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
10-13 13:35:47.132 12502-12598/com.example.dale.projectapp D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1080x1920]-format:1
10-13 13:35:47.212 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
10-13 13:35:47.262 12502-12598/com.example.dale.projectapp D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xde605800 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xf3536860
10-13 13:35:47.272 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@714354f time:18191994
10-13 13:35:47.492 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{708d76b token=android.os.BinderProxy@8bda5fa {com.example.dale.projectapp/com.example.dale.projectapp.Registration}} show : false
10-13 13:36:04.792 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:04.882 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:05.862 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:05.952 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:05.992 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.dale.projectapp time:18210718
10-13 13:36:06.192 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
10-13 13:36:06.202 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1d00858 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
10-13 13:36:06.212 12502-12598/com.example.dale.projectapp D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1080x1920]-format:1
10-13 13:36:06.222 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
10-13 13:36:06.312 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2cbb93b time:18211033
10-13 13:36:06.562 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
10-13 13:36:07.432 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:07.512 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:07.602 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:07.692 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:07.792 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:07.862 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:07.952 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:08.042 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:08.132 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:08.202 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:08.272 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:08.362 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:08.442 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:08.522 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:08.602 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:08.692 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:08.762 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:08.852 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:09.002 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:09.102 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:09.172 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:09.222 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:09.232 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:09.302 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:09.352 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:09.422 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:09.442 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:09.522 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:09.542 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:09.622 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:09.642 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:09.732 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:09.752 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:09.832 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:09.852 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:09.942 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:09.982 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:10.072 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:10.072 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:10.182 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:10.202 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:10.302 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:10.322 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:10.422 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:10.422 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:10.512 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:10.532 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:10.612 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:10.612 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:10.702 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:10.722 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:10.902 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:10.902 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:11.002 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:11.002 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:11.192 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:11.202 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:11.292 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:11.292 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:11.382 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:11.382 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:11.542 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:11.562 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:11.722 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:11.722 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:11.912 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:11.912 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:12.002 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:12.012 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:12.062 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:12.802 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:12.872 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:12.922 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:12.982 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:13.102 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:13.162 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:13.162 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:13.232 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-13 13:36:13.332 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-13 13:36:13.362 12502-12502/com.example.dale.projectapp D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
```

Comment: Plz attach Screenshot and logcat

Comment: `leftTrigger.setEnabled(false);` this is disabling your button

Comment: @UltimateDevil it is meant to work like that, if I remove the comment block, same thing happens. I am aware that I need to post in the handler thread to enable the button again, but even without the disable and enable button, this incident happens.

Comment: @HtooAungHlaing isnt the code sufficient enough? The log cat literally displays no related errors to the project. only the interaction logs such as touch coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

```
/Try to use Boolean flag to avoid multiple click until animation stops/

private boolean buttonClicked = false;

leftTrigger.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

      if(!buttonClicked)
      {
        call animation method
     Note: Once animation done set Boolean flag "True" ie: buttonClicked = true;
      } 
    }
});
```

Comment: wouldn't the first instance of `leftTrigger.setEnabled(false);` be enough? and the `leftTrigger.setEnabled(true);` of the `handler.post`?

Comment: @jamescastillo No James to avoid multiple clicks and heavy works on threads so leftTrigger.setEnabled(false); shouldn't be enough as you animating the view

Comment: so you mean even though the click event calls for disabling the button when clicked, there is a possibility that the event fires twice without going through the first code which is `leftTrigger.setEnabeld(false)`?

Comment: yes. and you should also check whether your button selector drawable have either clickable, selectable or Enabled. Beacuse your button selector drawable have clickable property and here you are calling enabled then it won't work